# Will Group Finisher Adrenaline Rush impede my other one?

Tags: the-witcher-2

When playing The Witcher 2 it is possible to obtain more than one Adrenaline Rush skill. As Witcher Wiki says, they are all activated simultaneously. I'm interested in getting the following ones:

> The alchemy tree's Adrenaline Rush is provided by the Mutant skill, which unleashes a special buff called '**Battle Frenzy**'. This buff is activated by pressing the x key when the Adrenaline bar is full. This buff augments Geralt, allowing him to regenerate vitality faster and pull off heavier hits with his main melee attacks.
>
> The swordsmanship tree's Adrenaline Rush is provided by the Combat acumen skill, which unleashes a special ability called '**Group Finishers**'. This ability is activated by pressing the x key when the Adrenaline bar is full. This ability gives Geralt the ability to kill the nearest three enemies, in a 'group finisher' move, **which is only possible if they all have relatively low health**.

After [Witcher Wikia](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Adrenaline_rush), emphasis mine

Say I do have both of those skills and am ready to use them both (adrenaline bar is full, displaying the "X" icon). Battle Frenzy is eligible to be used at any time in combat, while Group Finisher requires me to have at least one reasonably wounded enemy nearby. What happens if I'm in combat with enemies that would not qualify for a Group Finisher (full HP, reasonably armored) but try to use Adrenaline Rush nevertheless? I suppose one of the following will happen:

1. Complete success, Battle Frenzy is activated and Group Finisher requirement is overridden, killing three enemies that wouldn't qualify otherwise
2. Partial success, Battle Frenzy is activated, but Group Finisher is not.
3. Failure, I cannot use Adrenaline Rush at this time
4. Botch, I use the skill emptying the adrenaline bar, but due to Group Finisher being ineligible, Battle Frenzy is not activated as well.

Which one would it be? Or maybe something else will happen in the described situation?

Comment: I would guess 2. But I just can guess. Do you have both skills and can do some testing?

Comment: Not yet. That's why I'm asking, because I am about to start a playthrough with the idea of specing towards sword-centric stat monster. I want to get to the tops of Alchemy and Swordsmanship trees quickly and benefit from mutagen improvement AND more mutagen spaces, then pick up bread and butter of Alchemy with better potions and berserk mode, finally choosing all those nasty goodies from Swordsmanship (finisher, resistances, whirl etc.) for convenient monster-slashing. On top of that, it would give me fast adrenaline generation, but if it's 3 or 4, the build fails miserably.

Answer (score 1):

It is a partial success. I have tested it myself and if there were no eligible enemies, Group Finisher is just omitted and Battle Frenzy works normally.